# Howto do project structure "src/main/java" in eclipse`?

Tags: java, eclipse, program-entry-point, src, project-structure

sometimes i face project structures in Package Explorer that are at "src/main/java". But if i work for myself it is only "src". Howto take controll of that?

Difference between two projects in eclipse: left: one folder named "src/main/java" right: one folder named "src", one subfolder named "main.java"

[image]

Thanks - Enomine

Comment: Howto show the picture within this post? There was standing "enter image description here", so i did. But then image is not displayed.

Comment: Well, have you tried creating the "src/main/java" directories by yourself? Afterwards edit the build path and set "src/main/java" as "source folder".

Comment: Yes, i did. "milo0.3.0Server\src\main\java" exists

Comment: So the edit the build path, remove the entry for "src" and "add folder" where you select your "src/main/java" folder.

Comment: The source folder can be configured in _Project > Properties: Java Build Path_, tab _Sources_. The default source folder for plain Java projects (_New > Java Project_) is `src`, for Maven and Gradle projects it is `src/main/java`.

Comment: Does right-clicking the project and choosing _Maven > Update Project..._ change the source folder in the project shown in the picture on the right side to `src/main/java`?

Comment: @howlger, no it does not.

Comment: `src/main/java` is the Maven Standard Directory Layout, also used by Gradle. You should be using m2eclipse and treating your projects as Maven projects.

Comment: @Enomine Please show your `pom.xml` of the right side project.

Comment: And the contents of the `build.properties` file, if there is one.

Comment: @howlger , see below. (at)nitind , no is there.

Answer (score 2):

The **default source folder** for a Java **Maven** project is **`src/main/java`**. In the project on the right, the source folder is set to `src` via the following line in the `pom.xml` file:

```
<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
```

If you remove the line or change the value, right-click the project and choose ***Maven > Update Project...*** to have Eclipse read the `pom.xml` file and update the source folder location accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

**Difference:** Let's first understand the meaning of both the folders. In the left image src/main/java is the source folder which is used by eclipse to build the project. In the right image src is the source folder with the package main.java

**Solution:** It is not possible to edit your source folder So you have to copy your files and create a new source folder with name src/main/java.

Answer (score 0):

@howlger

[Project structure and pom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eb0yE.png)

I think i did right now. I clicked right, choosed "Build Path" -> "New Source Folder". Then it worked. With the Properties-Menue "Java Build Path" it didn't work.

Thanks - Enomine

Comment: Thanks for this information, but please add this information to your question (by clicking the _edit_ link at the bottom of the question) and delete this answer.

Answer (score 0):

The projects with `src/main/java` as *source* folder are **maven** projects. Maven is a build infrastructure which i.a. manages library dependencies, and provides conventions for the project folders, like `src/test/java` for unit test sources, and `src/main/resources` for non-java sources like images and *.properties files.

Best would be to import the project as *maven* project (here it is not *gradle*). It might be that you need a plugin in eclipse; for a while I am using an other IDE.

Create a new maven as trial.

Maven projects are controlled by a `pom.xml` so a recognition as maven project is best.

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, there are two ways how to solve it:
 1. go to project -> build path -> configure build path -> Java build path and then in source tab add your src/main/java folder
 2. There is also an arrow near the "Project explorer" which lets you customize your workspace. you can try to change "project presentation" or "package presentation"